# Dialog box quoting 'Object Reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: xamarin

When trying to create a simple Xamarin app, on debugging I will immediately get a dialog box quoting:

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Nothing appears in my error list.

Can anyone give me tips on where I am going wrong?

Many thanks,

Gary

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinApp1"
x:Class="XamarinApp1.MainPage">

<StackLayout>

<!-- Place new controls here -->
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
HorizontalOptions="Center"
VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
<Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinApp1

{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
int count = 0;

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
count++;
((Button)sender).Text = $"You clicked {count} times.";

}
}
```

**app.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace XamarinApp1
{
public partial class App : Application
{
public App()
{
InitializeComponent();
MainPage = new MainPage();
}
protected override void OnStart()
{
// Handle when your app starts
}
protected override void OnSleep()
{
// Handle when your app sleeps
}
protected override void OnResume()
{
// Handle when your app resumes
}
}  
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: How is your `App.xaml.cs` looks. Add that too.

Comment: the exception stack trace should tell you the source of the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I've now added the app.xaml.cs plus an image of the dialog box...

Comment: The code is okay, you try to delete “obj" and "bin" files and then rebuild

Comment: I've bin through my solution but I do not seem to have any “obj" and "bin" files

Comment: you could right click your solution --> Open Folder in File Explorer

Comment: I have tried this, and unfortunately it hasn't fixed the issue. But thank anyway. :)

Comment: Are your versions of Visual Studio and xamarin. Forms the latest ?